# SQL Server Express - Website not working

Tags: asp.net, iis, sql-server-express

I have a new website that I'm trying to deploy. It works great on my local machine, but when I install on the server, it no longer works and I don't get any error messages. I'm using SQL Server Express, but this isn't installed on the server. Do I need to do this?

Comment: can you provide the error code that you get in the error messages?

Comment: I dont get an error code.  That is my problem :o(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that you have TCP/IP settings enabled on the SQL Express you're trying to connect to in order to allow external connections.

It may also be worth while specifying a standard port rather than the dynamic ones it usually assigns so that you can add an exception to your firewall to allows access through this port if required.

Answer (score 2):

The database can be on any machine that is connected with the sever. All you need is to give the path of that machine hosting database in the connection string of your application

Answer (score 0):

Of course you need to install MS SQL or the Express version in the server. You then need to copy your database there and modify the connection strings in the Web.config.

The database server can also be located in another machine, as long as it allows remote access and the connection strings are set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so my problem was SQL Express didn't exist anywhere.  I installed it onto the Server and everything worked straight away (with the exception of changing my Integrated Security).  Thanks for all the pointers.